# inbound-channel-addapter take the first incoming file

Tags: spring-integration

I use inbound-channel-adapter which the following configuration:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="myAdapter"                        
                              directory="inDir"
                              auto-create-directory="true"
                              prevent-duplicates="true"
                              channel = "inChannel">
    <int:poller id="myPoller" cron="0/2 * * * * *"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

This channel adapter scans under the "inDir" to find new files. I want the first incoming file to be handled from the adapter as now I can see that the adapter takes the file with arithmetic or alphabetic order of the filenames. How can achieve the FIFO logic?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a custom `FileListFilter` that sorts the files.